# FFMPEG How to zoom in and then zoom out on video

Tags: ffmpeg

I have looked and researched a lot about the zoom in and zoom out commands, and looked at many related topics and found the answer that suits my needs, But unfortunately it only works for images, not for videos. Please help me.

''''"zoompan=z='if(lte(mod(on,42),10),zoom+0.0200,zoom-0.0065)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom)/2':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom)/2':d=500"''''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pzoom from https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zoompan

```
ffmpeg -i "input 1.mp4" -filter_complex "
zoompan=z='if(lte(mod(it*25,42),10),min(max(zoom,pzoom)+0.02,1.5),min(max(zoom,pzoom)-0.0065,1.5))':
x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':
y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':
d=1
" output.mp4 -y
```

play with numbers

Comment: 0


Thank you very much, you help me save a lot of time, And I wonder, what if we want to stop the interval about 20frames, after the zoomin and zoomout is end?

Comment: idk, maybe increase 42 to 62? `mod(it*25,62)` or more complex expression